# Figuring out what Ruby on Rails is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frameworks

Is RoR to Ruby equivalent to what the .NET framework is to VB.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

RoR is a rapid web application development framework.

.NET is a common language runtime, and VB.NET compiles to the CLR for VB code.

RoR would be equivalent to the ASP.NET MVC framework (with a bunch of time and magic and an amazingly flexible language).

Answer (score 1):

RoR is a framework (set of libraries) for making web sites.

Answer (score 1):

Nope!

You can go through this question to see [What is Ruby on Rails and why is it so famous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323083)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323083/what-is-ruby-on-rails-and-why-is-it-so-famous#323211) contains a link to the famous "Create a blog in 15 minutes with Ruby on Rails" It is VERY interesting to watch. Shows a lot of what RoR is all about and the way it is used to build apps.

Comment: All I can say is: thank god it's merging with Merb. Now it might not run like a wounded dog :)

Answer (score -2):

RoR is for developing dynamic web applications - which otherwise would have required php .But with RoR its very easy to write code for big web applications including ajaxifying it .i say its very easy and fast bcoz RoR is object-oriented.